# Javascript gestión de eventos

Tags: javascript, eventos

Existe alguna diferencia entre usar los eventos del propio objectos o es mejor usar un escuchador.

Ejemplo:

```html
<form href="#" method="get">
  
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
  
</form>
```

Cual de los métodos siguientes es mejor tanto en su manejabilidad como en el rendimiento.

```js
let f =  document.querySelector('form');
f.onsubmit = event => { /* FUNCION */ }
```

O mejor poner un escuchador

```js
let f = document.querySelector('form');
f.addEventListener("submit", event=>{ /*FUNCIÓN */ });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La principal diferencia es que con addEventListener puedes tener varios controladores para un mismo evento.

Esto te permite además añadir un controlador a un evento sin tener que preocuparte de si estás anulando un controlador anterior o no:

```js
function submit1(){
  alert('controlador 1');
}

function submit2(e){
  alert('controlador 2');
  e.preventDefault();
}

var f = document.querySelector('form');
f.addEventListener('submit', submit1);
f.addEventListener('submit', submit2);
```

```html
<form href="#" method="get">
  
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
  
</form>
```

Mientras que si utilizas la propiedad onsubmit:

```js
    function submit1(){
      alert('controlador 1');
    }

    function submit2(e){
      alert('controlador 2');
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    var f = document.querySelector('form');
    f.onsubmit = submit1;
    f.onsubmit = submit2;
```

```html
    <form href="#" method="get">
      
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" value="enviar">
      
    </form>
```

Al establecer el controlador submit2 anulas cualquier controlador anterior que se haya asociado al evento.